# Reverse a series within DataFrame to new column

Tags: python, pandas

How would I reverse the order of a series within a DataFrame into a new column?

```
data = [["US Dollar", 7.00],
        ['Euro', 2.00],
        ['British Pound', 4.00],
        ['Indian Rupee', 2.00],
        ['Australian Dollar', 9.00],
        ['Canadian Dollar', 3.00],
        ['Singapore Dollar', 3.00],
        ['Swiss Franc', 5.00]
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Currency', 'Order'])
```

I tried using loc to do this but that is giving me the same order back.

```
df['Reverse Order'] = df['Order'].iloc[::-1]
df


#   Currency            Order   Reverse Order
# 0 US Dollar           7.0     7.0
# 1 Euro                2.0     2.0
# 2 British Pound       4.0     4.0
# 3 Indian Rupee        2.0     2.0
# 4 Australian Dollar   9.0     9.0
# 5 Canadian Dollar     3.0     3.0
# 6 Singapore Dollar    3.0     3.0
# 7 Swiss Franc         5.0     5.0
```

I'm trying to get the reverse order such that

```
#   Currency            Order   Reverse Order
# 0 US Dollar           7.0     5.0
# 1 Euro                2.0     3.0
# 2 British Pound       4.0     3.0
# 3 Indian Rupee        2.0     9.0
# 4 Australian Dollar   9.0     2.0
# 5 Canadian Dollar     3.0     4.0
# 6 Singapore Dollar    3.0     2.0
# 7 Swiss Franc         5.0     7.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the values to numpy array (because now the index align back to original dataframe):

```py
df["Reverse Order"] = df.loc[::-1, "Order"].to_numpy()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Currency  Order  Reverse Order
0          US Dollar    7.0            5.0
1               Euro    2.0            3.0
2      British Pound    4.0            3.0
3       Indian Rupee    2.0            9.0
4  Australian Dollar    9.0            2.0
5    Canadian Dollar    3.0            4.0
6   Singapore Dollar    3.0            2.0
7        Swiss Franc    5.0            7.0
```

Comment: It was reversing the series but keeping the original indices.  One way or another I had to drop the index to keep the ordering of the values. Very good.

Answer (score 3):

using `values` gives the **numpy array**

so just use this to get the result.

```py
df['Reverse Order'] = df['Order'].values[::-1]
print(df)
```

```
            Currency  Order  Reverse Order
0          US Dollar    7.0            5.0
1               Euro    2.0            3.0
2      British Pound    4.0            3.0
3       Indian Rupee    2.0            9.0
4  Australian Dollar    9.0            2.0
5    Canadian Dollar    3.0            4.0
6   Singapore Dollar    3.0            2.0
7        Swiss Franc    5.0            7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['Order'].iloc[::-1]` creates a `Series` that still has the original index. Pandas honors the index when assigning a `Series` to a column in the dataframe. You can drop the index before assignment to get it to work:

```
df['Reverse Order'] = df['Order'].iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: That will only work if the original index is a default range index, using the underlying numpy array is much safer. Or eventually using `df['Order'].iloc[::-1].set_axis(df.index)`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, reset the index of the reversed series before assigning it to the new column. Then the order is preserved.

```py
df['Reverse Order'] = df['Order'].iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Here's the output:

```
           Currency  Order  Reverse Order
0         US Dollar    7.0            5.0
1              Euro    2.0            3.0
2     British Pound    4.0            3.0
3      Indian Rupee    2.0            9.0
4 Australian Dollar    9.0            2.0
5   Canadian Dollar    3.0            4.0
6  Singapore Dollar    3.0            2.0
7       Swiss Franc    5.0            7.0
```

Comment: This is identical to the solution by @tdelaney, but you are still correct.

Comment: This is the exact same code as [tdelaney's answer](/a/77164747/4518341), which was posted about 40 minutes earlier. Please don't post duplicate answers.